# Checkbox in expanadblelist childview

Tags: checkbox, expandablelistview

I have a checkbox in childview of expandablelistview and set data according to list, now if i selected group from top to bottom then it will work fine but if i select random positions of group then another checkbox in child is selected also if i change the state of checkbox then it will randomly change state of another checkbox

```
public class FilterExpandableViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private HashMap < Integer, Integer > mChildCheckStates = new HashMap < > ();

    private List < FacetView > facetViewList = new ArrayList < FacetView > ();
    private ArrayList < ArrayList < Boolean >> checkStates = new ArrayList < ArrayList < Boolean >> ();

    public FilterExpandableViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setData(List < FacetView > facetViewList) {
        this.facetViewList = facetViewList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return facetViewList == null ? 0 : facetViewList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return facetViewList == null ? 0 : this.facetViewList.get(i).getEntry().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return this.facetViewList.get(i).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return this.facetViewList.get(i).getEntry().get(i1).getLabel();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(i);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_parent_list_view, null);
        }

        TextView tvheading = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_filter_header);
        tvheading.setText(listTitle);

        ImageView imgViewArrow = view.findViewById(R.id.img_view_arrow_filter);

        if (b) {
            imgViewArrow.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_down_grey_25dp));
            imgViewArrow.setRotation(180);
        } else {
            imgViewArrow.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_down_grey_25dp));
            imgViewArrow.setRotation(0);
        }


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ChildHolder childHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.filter_child_view, null);
            childHolder = new ChildHolder();
            childHolder.checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_filter_child_view);
            view.setTag(childHolder);
        } else {
            childHolder = (ChildHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        childHolder.checkBox.setText(getChild(i, i1).toString());

        childHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkStates.get(i).get(i1));
        String expandedListText = (String) getChild(i, i1);
        String hasMultipleSelection = facetViewList.get(i).getExtendedData().getAllowMultipleValueSelection();
        childHolder.checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_filter_child_view);
        childHolder.checkBox.setText(expandedListText + " check box");
        if (hasMultipleSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

        }
        if (hasMultipleSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {

            try {
                childHolder.checkBox.setChecked(i1 == mChildCheckStates.get(i));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            childHolder.checkBox.setTag(i1);

            childHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(view1 - > {
                mChildCheckStates.put(i, (Integer) view1.getTag());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            });
        }
        return view;
    }

    class ChildHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        Boolean state = false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }
```